# Executing the next function in the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I`m working on a interactive story using Jquery, my question is, since 
the 1st text is loaded on the function scene1, after the button .slideBt1 is clicked, how can the 2nd text function be executed by the same button, working like a next button?

```
function scene1 () {
$("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");

//1st text
$('.slideBt1').click(function(){
$('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000);
});

//2nd text
$('.slideBt1').click(function(){
$('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: Instead of having different clicks, you could have the text you need to show, in an Array and onclick of the button show the next element of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some flag to toggle between them

```
function scene1() {
  $("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");
  $('.slideBt1').click(function() {
    if (!this.toggle)
      $('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    else
      $('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
  });
}
```

```js
$("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");
$('.slideBt1').click(function() {
  if (!this.toggle)
    $('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000);
  else
    $('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000);
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<button class="slideBt1">click</button>
```

If you want to remove click handler after reaching the last text,

```js
$("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");
var abc = function() {
  if (!this.toggle)
    $('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000);
  else {
    $('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    $('.slideBt1').off('click', abc);
  }
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
};
$('.slideBt1').on('click', abc);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<button class="slideBt1">click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I gona try your sugestion guys.

Comment: Pranav C Balan, how can I toggle 3 functions or more?

Comment: @FernandoSouza : In that case you need to do something like Ankit Mishra's answer :)

Comment: Thank you, so I will work with arrays. Its a shame that toggle method was erased in version 1.9...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having different clicks, you could have the text you need to show, in an Array and onclick of the button show the next element of array.

If you need different actions/animation at different points in story, then you would need to store the animations in your array as well.

```js
var story = ["Nice to meet you!", "what is your name", "Other sentence...", "Yet another sentence"];
var clickCount = 0;

$("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");

var nextStatment = function() {
  $('p').text(story[clickCount]).hide().fadeIn(1000);
  clickCount++;
  //Here you might need to reset the count to 0, if it exceeds the array size.
};

$('.slideBt1').on('click', nextStatment);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<button class="slideBt1">click</button>
```

Comment: Hi, so I decided to put more information on the array (functions), in this case an object would be better. How can I access the functions inside an object so called "story", by clickCount?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger click event using code in jQuery, something like below:

```
function scene1 () {
   $("p").text("Hi! My name is Lombado");
   $('.slideBt1').trigger("click");
}
```